# Firefox (snap) in Kubuntu 22.04 fails to restore session upon start

Tags: firefox, snap, restore, session

There are some questions about FF either not saving or failing completely to restore a previous session, but they do not cover my problem:

When I start FF (119.0b9 (64-bit)), it tells me it cannot restore the session but when I click on the button "Restore Session" (iirc), it restores the previous session perfectly.

I'd like it to do that automatically as it used to with the 20.04 version.

Josef